Synonym for "to follow from"
I would like to rewrite the following sentence:

The scaling arguments do not follow automatically from the equations of motion.

Could I say that

They are not a direct consequence from the equations of motion
They do not automatically arise as a consequence of the equations of motion?


The scaling arguments do not derive  automatically from the equations of motion.

@669 That's an answer, if you can find a definition of the sense of 'derive from' involved.

For my money, They are not a direct consequence of the equations of motion. But what's wrong with the original that leads you to want to rewrite it?

And an etymological note: The word consequence derives from the Latin verb sequor, which means… follow! So your proposed rewrites have a bit of the flavor of simply replacing a verb with its corresponding noun form. Not that your typical user of English would know this…

Are you looking for a specific logical relationship (e.g. A logically entails B)? Or a more informal type of connection?

The scaling arguments are not directly deducible from the equations of motion.

Another term is "proceed from".

(OLD) proceed from phrasal verb
proceed from something
(formal) to be caused by or be the result of something

In some cases appeals may proceed directly from the High Court to the House of Lords.


proceeds from the equations

The verbal idiom "stem from" can be used.

(OLD) stem from  phrasal verb
stem from something
​(not used in the progressive tenses) to be the result of something

Most people’s insecurities stem from something that happened in their childhood.


(The Credit Crunch and Regulatory Burdens in Bank Lending: ...
United States. Congress. House. Committee on Government Operations. Commerce, Consumer, and Monetary Affairs Subcommittee · 1993) The questions and points in the letter do not stem directly from the existing bank regulations.
stem from the axioms
